# Google OAuth Auth. Provider doesn't ask for offline access

Tags: oauth2, google-apps, google

I set up an Auth. Provider for Google Apps as explained in the [Salesforce Help](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_files_connect_google_auth.htm), but Salesforce doesn't seem to ask for offline access so I have to go through the "connect" flow every hour, when I want to access the files on my Google Drive.

The *Authorize Endpoint URL* is `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force`, but when I enter the actual OAuth flow, those parameters seem to be dropped. The URL I'm redirected to looks like this:

`https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?continue=https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope%3Demail%2Bopenid%2Bprofile%2Bhttps://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive%26response_type%3Dcode%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps://login.salesforce.com/services/authcallback/[...]/Google_Apps%26state%3D[...]%26client_id%3D[...]%26hl%3Den-US%26from_login%3D1%26as%3D[...]&ltmpl=nosignup&btmpl=authsub&hl=en_US&scc=1&oauth=1`

The `access_type` and `approval_prompt` parameters are nowhere to be seen in the `continue` URL. For my admin login I added it manually when going through the login flow, but I can't really do that for all my users.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Is this a (known) bug? (couldn't find it on their [Known Issues](https://success.salesforce.com/issues) site)

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing happen.  Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Not yet (haven't spent much time on it since then, though). Worst thing is that the OAuth dialog doesn't appear in Salesforce1, so when the token has expired, you have to go back and log in on a desktop :/

Comment: thats a bummer.  Did you open a support case?  It definitely sounds like a bug (although I doubt they will do anything to fix it)